# How to make a circular countdown / gauge to show days left in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-svg

I want to make a circular progress bar which shows the number of days to expire like nowadays we see an airtel payment app which has a circular disc which shows daily data left, validity, etc..
i wanted to implement something like that....in react native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the best library , and ive used this for progress circle

[react-native-svg-charts](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts#progresscircle) , do check this out. Implementation is easy.

[image]

Do reach out in case of any concerns

Comment: and how can I put text inside the circle and  for 30 days it should complete the circle and show expired

Comment: make a text view and absolute the position?